# Spork fails to start with no such file to load -- spork (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, spork

Whenever I run `spork`, I get

```
$ spork
Using RSpec
Preloading Rails environment
Loading Spork.prefork block...
no such file to load -- spork (LoadError)
/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/Users/darth/projects/checkin/spec/spec_helper.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `block in load'
/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/test_framework.rb:138:in `block (2 levels) in preload'
/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/app_framework/rails.rb:8:in `preload'
/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/test_framework.rb:134:in `block in preload'
/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork.rb:62:in `exec_prefork'
/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/test_framework.rb:120:in `preload'
/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:25:in `preload'
/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/runner.rb:74:in `run'
/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/lib/spork/runner.rb:10:in `run'
/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc9/bin/spork:10:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/spork:19:in `load'
/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/spork:19:in `<main>'
```

I remember already having spork working couple days ago, but I was messing around with my Gemfile to get it working on Heroku, and I can't seem to get it to work now. Here's my Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rack', '1.3.3'
gem 'rails', '3.1.0'
gem 'json'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'pg', :group => :production

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'nifty-generators', :group => :development

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  group :darwin do
    gem 'rb-fsevent', :require => false
    gem 'rb-inotify', :require => false
    gem 'rb-fchange', :require => false
  end
  gem 'spork', '> 0.9.0.rc'
  gem 'guard-rspec', :require => false
  gem 'guard-spork', :require => false
  gem 'growl'
  gem 'cucumber-rails'  
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'webrat'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'  
end
```

When I try to launch spork in another project it seems to work just fine, so the problem must be somewhere in the configuration.

`bundle exec spork` gives me

```
/Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-
1.0.21/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:143:in `block in replace_gem': 
     spork is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
     from /Users/darth/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/spork:18:in `<main>'
```

Comment: what do you have line 2 of your spec_helper file?

Comment: `require 'spork'` ... I haven't really modified spec_helper file after it was bootstrapped

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this in 3.1.0 yet so it might not work but in your spork prefork.. try adding the following:

```
Spork.prefork do
...
   #Add this following line to get spork working with rails 3
   ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear
...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me in rails 3.  Make sure 'spork-rails' is in your gemfile. 
I just see 'spork' in yours.

I've tried to use it outside of bundler since its not in the team project and nobody wants it in there, but it wouldn't work unless I actually had it in the gemfile.